# Is there a way to put unsent SMS messages in a system queue to be sent whenever service is back?

Tags: android

I am building an android app that will fetch the device location and send it in an SMS to a specified number every certain interval.
My problem is that if the SMS was not sent, say for no service, I want the app to send all the unsent messages whenever the service is back.
So, my question is, is there a built in function to do that? or do i have to add all the unsent messages in a database? any suggestions?

Comment: Adding unsent messages to a database sounds like a good idea. Then at the next "interval" you send your message as usual + the unsent messages, if any.

Comment: you can make sure your messages are added to the user message inbox. however even that does not send the messages by itself. so you need to save the messages by yourself, based on the result code you receive